# Find the residue of $\cos(z)/(z^2+a^2)^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

This is part of a larger question, but I need to find the residue of the following function at $z = \pm ai$:
$$f(z) = \frac{\cos(z)}{(z^2+a^2)^2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case both $+ai$ and $-ai$ are poles of order $n=2$

$$
f(z) = \frac{\cos z}{(z+ ai)^2(z- ai)^2}
$$

In general if $c$ is pole of order $n$ then

> $$
> {\rm Res}_f(c) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z\to c}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left[(z-c)^n f(z)\right]
> $$

So you need to evaluate this expression for $n=2$ and $c = \pm ai$. This is the result

$$
{\rm Res}_f(ai) = \frac{i (a \sinh a-\cosh a)}{4 a^3} \quad a\ne 0
$$

and

$$
{\rm Res}_f(-ai) = -\frac{i (a \sinh a-\cosh a)}{4 a^3} \quad a\ne 0
$$

If $a = 0$ the pole is order 4 and

$$
\rm{Res_f}(0) = 0
$$